# rDotNet CLRServer.exe not found

Tags: r, clr, r.net

I am trying to access a C# dll within R using rDotNet. Note that I am not at all well versed in C# and Visual studio.

In R, when I try to run the `.cinit()` function for the first time, I get:

```
NOTE: starting CLR server
Warning message:
In system2(exe, args, wait = FALSE, stderr = FALSE, stdout = FALSE) :
  '"C:/Users/User/Dropbox/My PC (DESKTOP-T9I5J)/Documents/R/win- 
library/3.6/rDotNet/server/bin/Debug/CLRServer.exe"' not found
```

Subsequent attempts to use any functions such as `.cnew` results in:

```
Error in internal_cnew(classname, argv) : 
problem communicating with CLR, could not complete message
```

I have done multiple searches for `CLRServer.exe`, both on my computer and on the internet. There is almost no reference to it anywhere! The only place where the existence of this file is mentioned is within the rDotNet documentation, and I otherwise have absolutely no idea where to obtain this .exe.

I have rDotNet installed both through R and as a package in Visual Studio. I tracked down the `nuget` and `msbuild` files and added them to my path. All I need to do is locate this CLRServer.exe.

Comment: How did you install rDotNet?

Comment: @HongOoi I first installed it through R using the inbuilt utils:::menuInstallPkgs() and after that gave problems I subsequently installed it through NuGet in Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# but it looks like you need to build a debug executable. There should be a switch somewhere in VS for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is here in this repo and if you don't know how to build a dotnet project then the binary can be downloaded from here:

https://github.com/tr8dr/.Net-Bridge/tree/master/bin/Debug

Grab all the files(executable &dlls)

Comment: Well things have progressed from this error to a different error. Nevertheless, thanks for this response.

Comment: if it is dotnet related i might be able to help